# Update installed packages automatically

Tags: community, package

I am working in a team and we are using one development org that we are installing our packages into. Do I need to uninstall and install my package everytime I create a new package version? Or is there an package manage command like npm update for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you are developing an unlocked package and other people are developing other unlocked packages as well. After that you install them into a developer org to test.

If that's the case, then you don't need to do anything besides installing the newest version of your package into the org. In API version 45.0 and later (salesforcedx plug-in for Salesforce CLI version 45.0.9 or later), you can specify [what happens to removed metadata during package upgrade](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_unlocked_pkg_install_pkg_upgrade.htm). Use the `force:package:install` command’s `-t | --upgradetype`.

Please read the [documentation on Unlocked Packages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_unlocked_pkg_intro.htm).

Comment: So if my package has my colleague's package as dependency. Do I need to manually modify the sfdx-project.json every time my colleague update his package?

Comment: ...and generate a new package version with the updated dependency? I believe so. I haven't tested it myself, but considering that you can't update the package's content after building it, this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

If your package is a Managed Package or Unlocked Package, you can "install" it as an update using [Salesforce DX CLI](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/sfdxcli):

```
sfdx force:package:install --package "package@1.2.3"
```

If your package is an Unmanaged Package, you must uninstall the old version to install the new.

I strongly recommend using Unlocked Packages if you're not packaging for the AppExchange, as Managed Packages have significant limitations, and Unmanaged Packages are very difficult to work with for non-trivial projects.